# Why only humans become ghosts but never any other organism?

Tags: yoga, death, gita, jivatman, paramatma

Why only humans become ghosts/returning spirit, while there are uncountable organisms dying but never turn ghost.

Is it because of the subconscious mind and it's strong memories to achieve something before attaining peace and moving ahead for another soulful journey?

There's desires in any accidently dying organism as well but there's none returns whatsoever after dying except humans, like scientists carry out innumerable experiments on innocently dying creatures but they die and that's it.

But if human is killed/dies he might come back to take revenge/fulfill some wish if he wills to while dying or might curse as well and it works in many circumstances.

Comment: Animals, like all living organisms, have jivas. When an animal dies, it's jiva continues its karmic journey into another living organism.

Comment: Mind (manas), intellect (buddhi) and ego (ahankara) without indriyas is a tormented existence. For species less than human, there is no possibility of sin as they can only act according to prakriti and there is no development of consciousness. To be condemned to live as a ghost is a punishment. This is what I've learned but have no shastrika pramana...

Comment: There mind is not developed like humans except one crocodile which  lives mangalore temple which doesn't eat nonveg takes only prasadam vishnu similarly Gajendra elephant